# Why is bad practice to use autocommit in SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The official manual said that using auto commit not for general use:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_transaction.html

But i get ORM object (table values) in my code, and in code i using some values of this model, it's mean that after each using member of model (class) i should make session.commit()? I think it easy to enable autocommit in my program.

```
class DBInterface(object):
def __init__(self):
    engine = create_engine("...", encoding='utf8', echo=False)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    self.session = Session()

def get_project_info(self, project):
    query = self.session.query(Projects)
    query = query.filter(Projects.name == project).all()
    if len(query) > 1:
        raise LookupError('...')
    result = query[0]
    self.session.commit() 
    return result
```

get values
x = get_project_info(...)
// here we have't not closed transaction (idle in transaction)

print(x.foo) // now we print value of member and, now we have (idle in transaction)
// self.session.commit() // should i use thin after each access? it's crazy

What shall I do?

Comment: From the description it sounds like it places every query into its own transaction, which effectively defeats the purpose of transactions.  You'd have no transaction boundary, no meaningful unit of work, and no optimizations for multiple queries in a given session.

Comment: You don't need to commit after reading. You should commit after writing to persist your data. It's generally better to commit manually, since you can execute multiple queries inside one transaction (which is not possible with autocommit). Also note, that once you commit current transaction SA will start new one for you automatically.

Comment: In simpler terms, the above comments are pointing out that autocommit prevents the use of rollback. Using autocommit, if you get half-way through a series of related updates and hit an error, you have a half-updated database.  Using transactions you can rollback to the state prior to starting the updates.